# CSS media queries for Amazon Kindle Web Browser

Tags: css, kindle

We'd like to use a higher contrast style for our web page on Kindle web browser for e-ink displays. However Kindle uses regular `screen` media type. There is mention of using `amzn-mobi` and `amzn-kf8` media types for Kindle but they seem to be applicable only to e-books, not to the web browser.

We can always look into the user agent string and add a class accordingly but we'd like to avoid JavaScript based solutions as much as possible when there is a CSS-based alternative.

Comment: So `@media amzn-mobi{/*higher contrast styles*/}` does not work? From http://kindlegen.s3.amazonaws.com/AmazonKindlePublishingGuidelines.pdf

Comment: No it doesn't. Those are only applicable to e-books, not web pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We decided to skip that venture because:

- Kindle isn't the only e-book reader
- Not every Kindle is e-ink
- There is no simple compatible method to detect e-ink displays

For such reasons we decided to postpone implementing any specific styles and went with increasing the default contrast in the design.